# Idiomatic way to initialize a Ruby class

Tags: ruby

What is the idiomatic way to initialize a `Person` object? I personally prefer `person2` but I am new to Ruby.

```
class Person
    attr_reader :first, :middle, :last, :phone_number

    def initialize(first, middle, last, phone_number)
        @first = first
        @middle = middle
        @last = last
        @phone_number = phone_number
    end
end

if caller.length == 0
    person1 = Person.new("John", "T", "Smith", "555-5555")
    person2 = Person.new(
        first=       "John",
        middle=      "T",
        last=        "Smith", 
        phone_number="555-5555",
    )
end
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Typically in ruby, objects are created either like `person1` or in the following fashion:

```
class Person
    attr_reader :first, :middle, :last, :phone_number

    def initialize(options)
        @first = options[:first]
        @middle = options[:middle]
        @last = options[:last]
        @phone_number = options[:phone_number]
    end
end

person = Person.new(first: "John", middle: "T", last: "Smith", phone_number"555-5555")
```

The nice thing about this alternate approach, is that you can optionally include as many or as few of the attributes as you like, as well as allow an arbitrary ordering.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I've seen something similar in Python with `def __init__(self, **kwargs)`. My personal opinion is that this makes the initializer very hard to read. `options` or `**kwargs` doesn't tell me anything about what to pass to the initializer, so I have to dig into the implementation logic to understand how to properly initialize the object. I think I will stick with the `person1` example for now :)

Answer (score 1):

```
person1 = Person.new("John", "T", "Smith", "555-5555")
```

Is a better option in my opinion. There will be some that will disagree, but here is why I think that.

First of all, you should write your code to be as readable as possible. That way, people don't have to ask many questions to understand why something is written/built the way it is. So, if you do it the second way, you will be over explaining. But, by doing it the second way, it is like admitting to people reading your code that it wasn't written as well as it could have been the first time. Any developer of your software would know that they could look at the constructor parameter names or your IDE would already specify with a form of auto documentation. An alternative to both of the notation above would be to initialize the persons name in the constructor as follows

```
person1 = Person.new("John Smith")
```

or even better...

```
person1 = Person.new()
```

And then set the fields as necessary to explain what is happening.

```
person1.address = "Blah street"
person1.phoneNumber = "555-5555"
```

Now, while I completely understand why the second one might look better, it hurts in the long run. Its unnecessary fluff in the code and is better removed through leaner design and or powerful tools.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. If I explicitly set the fields (i.e. `person1.address = "blah"`) then I would have to change the `address` field from `attr_reader` to `attr_accessor`. Again, I'm new to Ruby, but wouldn't it make sense to be as restrictive as possible with access control?

Comment: To be honest, I am not a primary Ruby developer. I spent about 2 years with Ruby, but primarily work in C# so my suggestions should be taken with a grain of salt. When it comes to being as restrictive as possible, it depends on how you plan to use the object during it's lifetime. If it is supposed to act as a constant of sorts and be passed between parts of a system, then yes, I would say stick with constructor initialization or something more elaborate specific to your environment. Otherwise, you will need to expose setters of some form which would work. Best case you could use a factory.